# How to concatenate an array list to a constant value in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a variable called Assignedmonth in jQuery which is storing multiple items selected from a dropdown list

```
AssignedMonth = $('#dlAssignedMonth :selected').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

And one more variable AssignedYear which is storing just one item selected from a list.

```
AssignedYear = $('#dlAssignedYear').val();
```

Now I want to concatenate these two variable and want the result in below format.

```
Jan-2017
Feb-2017
Mar-2017
```

Similarly for the rest of the month.

I tried `$.each()` function in js file but couldn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Just `prefix` year to the `$(this).text()` before returning

```
var year = $('#dlAssignedYear').val();

var output = $('#dlAssignedMonth :selected').map( function () { 
  return year + " " + $(this).text();  //this line has been changed to prefix year
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function on arrays in JS and `template strings` in ES-6 to simplify strings.

```
var result = AssignedMonth.map(function(month){
    return `${month}-${AssignedYear}`;
})
```